# add more to listview with out calling notifydataset

Tags: android, android-listview

im trying to create a feed like instagram. When the user reaches the bottom of the listview more pics should be added to the listview. Is there a way to add more to the listview with out calling notifyDataSetChanged() because it causes the listview to flicker.

Comment: Try creating a new Adapter or re-initializing the Adapter being used with added data then set that Adapter to the ListView.

Comment: @HuyTran- I tried that. It takes me back to the top of the listview

Comment: What will happen if you set the Adapter then set the position too?

Comment: @HuyTran-how do you set the position?

Comment: Use `setSelection(int position)`.

Comment: So I guess I should post it as an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new Adapter or re-initializing the Adapter being used with added data then set that Adapter to the ListView.

Then use `setSelection(int position)` to move to the bottom of the ListView.